# How to download JSON by gson?

Tags: java, android

I want to download a JSON data which is in square brackets. I use gson but I don't know how to handle with it.

My example JSON:

```
[ 20008943, 20009017, 20008466, 20007638, 20008709, 20007813, 20008257, 20000649, 20006525, 20008313]
```

And here is my code

```
 JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); 
 JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream)request.getContent())); 
                JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); 
                String jsonContent = rootobj.get("").getAsString();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the example above isn't a JSON example !  --> see how JSON is [json examples](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)

here's an example for using the gson API to deal with JSON Objects

```
//from object to JSON 
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(yourObject);

// from JSON to object 
yourObject o = gson.fromJson(JSONString,yourObject.class);
```

to get JSON data from URL

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
    TextView tv;
    String ab;
    JSONObject jobj = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        new retrievedata().execute();

    }

    class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://myurlhere.com");

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", jobj.toString());

            try {
                ab = jobj.getString("title");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ab;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String ab){

            tv.setText(ab);
        }

    }

}
```